How can I remove all chacters after a specific character in a string, using Python 3 OR Arcade in ArcPro 2.8?
I have a column ("NAME") in which there is data such as "Melbourne depot (Parks)" or "Orbost depot (Dept)".
I want to remove all data from and including the "(" so that I end up with "Melbourne depot", etc.  How can I do this, please?
I'm hoping that there is a single line of code in Calculate Field that can achieve this. I'm a novice in writing commands.
I've tried the following commands:
!NAME!.split("(")[0]
and
!NAME!.strip("(")[0]
and
my_string="Rainbow depot (Parks)"
print(my_string.split("(",1)[1])

and this also:
def substring_after(s, delim):
    return s.partition(delim)[2]

s1="Rainbow depot (Parks)"
substring_after(s1, "(")

All of these produced errors - I suspect my syntax may be wrong in some of these.

if your syntax is wrong you would get an error, are you getting one? otherwise you might want to say that you are doing semantic mistakes?

Found an answer: !NAME!.split("(", 1)[0].  This worked.
